# Como usar uma máscara para datas no Angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Eu tenho um formulário na minha aplicação onde o usuário pode editar diversos dados, inclusive sua data de nascimento. No campo de editar a data estou usando esse input:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="name">Data Nascimento</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                formControlName="dataNascimento"
                class="form-control" 
                id="name"
                mask="{{maskDtNascimento}}"
                [dropSpecialCharacters]="false"
                placeholder="00/00/0000"
                [readOnly]="justRead"
                required
              />
</div>
```

A variável `maskDtNascimento` é a seguinte:

```js
 maskDtNascimento = '00/00/0000';
```

O problema é que dessa forma esse input me permite colocar datas num formato errado, como essa:

[image: input com máscara de data]

Estou usando o Angular 10  e ngx-mask nesse projeto. Minha dúvida é: como fazer com que esse input não permita o usuário digitar datas inválidas e ainda mostrar o valor formatado corretamente?

Comment: O **mask** não faz validações de dados, apenas, formata. Para isso terá que criar uma função que pega os dados e verifica se os valores são válidos. Agora acho bobagem perder tempo com isso, se é um input e o que quer é pegar uma data, eu utilizaria um simples input do tipo date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está utilizando o ngx-mask, tente colocar dessa maneira:

```js
     
        maskDtNascimento = 'd0/M0/0000';
```

Na documentação do ngx-mask possui vários exemplos de uso, já com as validações para as máscaras que precisar.